# Any way to avoid all the "this" in Javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, object

When defining a JS object with a constructor function, is there any way to avoid having to use "this" with every single object property? It seems very ugly. E.g.

```
function Thingy(abc) {
  this.var1 = abc;
  this.var2 = this.var1 + " hello ";
  // etc
}

var myObj = new Thingy();
```

It seems that I should be able to use "var var2" and then leave out the "this" and just refer to "var2", but am I missing something?

Comment: You can avoid to use them. But they provide some lisibility in some cases, and avoid ambiguity when variables with the same name but different scopes.

Comment: You can easily use `var var2 = 42` and refer to the value as `var2`, but the question is, what purpose your function has?!

Comment: You can do `var var2`, but if you do, `var2` will only be accessable *inside* `Thingy` (it'll be private).

Comment: You can use `var`, but it will make the variables private. As in, the only place you have access to them is your function's scope. You wouldn't be able to use `myObj.var1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm afraid that you're running into how the language is designed.

But there is a sense in which you can use the plain `var` statements from the constructor.  Any functions created in there have access to the closure that includes these properties:

```
function Thingy(abc) {
    var var1 = abc;
    this.func1 = function(str) {return var1 + ", hello";};
}

var thing1 = new Thingy("Dan");
thing1.func1();  // => "Dan, hello"
```

Note this is how you can encapsulate entirely private variables in an object, so it's often a useful technique.

Comment: Thanks! This would seem to be the best "default" way to do it in fact, the only difference I can see is that thing1.var1 is no longer accessible, giving more privacy and much cleaner code. Strange that all the examples I have found using this object constructor method use the "this".

Comment: There is a substantial downside to this as well, though.  Note that prototype functions do not have access to this property.  The language forces tradeoffs between extreme encapsulation and better memory management.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any object you like and simply `return` it at the end e.g.:

```
function Thingy(abc) {
  var thingy = {};
  thingy.var1 = abc;
  thingy.var2 = thingy.var1 + " hello ";
  return thingy;
}
```

Or

```
function Thingy(abc) {
  var thingy = {
    var1: abc,
    var2: abc + " hello "
  };
  return thingy;
}
```

Or

```
function Thingy(abc) {
  return {
    var1: abc,
    var2: abc + " hello "
  };
}
```

Or

```
function Thingy(abc) {
  var var1 = abc,
      var2 = var1;
  var2 += " hello ";
  return {
    var1: var1,
    var2: var2
  };
}
```

Comment: But of course many of those introduce certain inefficiencies, throwing away the initially created `this` object.

Comment: I didn't say it was more efficient, I simply answered his question :)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there's no way to avoid it. You need to use `this` to assign variables to an object.

Comment: provide a quote to support your statement?

Comment: @Samuel: What kind of quote would you expect? If you'd write `var1 = ...` you would create a global variable (or assign the value to a variable defined in a higher scope). `var var1 = ...` would create a local variable. Assigning a property to an object is always done with `obj.propertyName = ...`, so you have to use `this.propertyName = ...`. I can quote the spec if you want: http://es5.github.com ;)

Comment: @FelixKling So what's wrong with creating a local variable and using a "getter"? The OP asked if there were **any** way to avoid using `this`. I think ScottSauyet's answer is correct. At the same time, it depends what the OP is trying to do, to determine what's worth what. And it's not like it's using a lot of extra/confusing code or something to make it crazy. But his answer is definitely applicable, so the answer "Nope" doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: @Ian: My answer does not contradict FelixKing's comment.  You can achieve hidden data in this manner, but I also know of no way to setting the public properties of the current object without using `this`.  As another answer suggested, you can return an entirely different object out of a constructor function, without using `this`, but working with the current object, I believe you have to use `this`, directly or indirectly.

Comment: @Ian: Of course there are ways to avoid using `this`, but as you said, it depends on whether it's applicable in the OP's situation. While Scott's answer might be an alternative, the result certainly differs from the OP's code. You *could* take this one step further and use `Object.defineProperty` with closures, but IMO this does more harm than good.

Comment: @ScottSauyet True, but in any solution with public exposure, the use of `this` will appear at least once. Whether that be with storing a reference to `this` and using the reference, or whatever. But I guess the point is that if something needs to be made public, `this` will have to be used. Of course, there's `Object.defineProperty` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty ), but that doesn't seem any cleaner in the slightest

Comment: @Ian: I thought that was what I said!  :-)

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yeah I think I just needed to type it out myself to make sure I understood :)

Comment: @FelixKling Definitely. I guess my point is that just saying "Nope" isn't 100% correct, as their are partial workarounds, while saying "Here's a solution with private vars" isn't 100% correct either because it still has to use `this` in some form (possibly)...and as we've determined, it depends on the developer's need. :)

Answer (score -2):

try

```
function Thingy(abc) {
  with(this)
  {
    var1 = abc;
    var2 = this.var1 + " hello ";
  // etc
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Comment: I'm upvoting this with the caveat that it is not very good programming practice...  Too confusing for the developer to know that 'var1' means 'this.var1'...  My $0.02...

Comment: `with` does not work this way and will throw an error in strict mode. This will create `var1` and `var2` in global scope.